# How to remove a Namespaceprefix of an attribute?

Tags: c#, xml

In the Last few Days i was trying to remove a Prefix of a Namespace of a Node.
With some help i got it finished:

Xml (before):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1assembly.adaptive.xsd"
manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2"
xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:co.v1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1"
xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3"
xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
xmlns:co.v2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
 <asmv1:assemblyIdentity name="Executable.exe"/>
 <description asmv2:iconFile="Icon.ico" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="preRequisite">
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="install">
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
    <file name="Populatedfile.dll.deploy" size="123">
    </file>
```

C# Code:

```
 var doc = XDocument.Load("Xmlfile");
 doc.Root.Attribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "asmv2").Remove();
 XNamespace ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2";
 doc.Descendants(ns + "dependentAssembly")
     .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("dependencyType") == "install")
     .Select(x => x.Parent)
     .Remove();
 doc.Descendants(ns + "file").Remove();
 doc.Save("XmlFile");
```

Xml (after):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1 assembly.adaptive.xsd"
manifestVersion="1.0"
xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:co.v1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1" 
xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3"
xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
xmlns:co.v2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
<asmv1:assemblyIdentity name="Executable.exe" />
<description p8:iconFile="Icon.ico" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:p8="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" />
<dependency>
 <dependentAssembly dependencyType="preRequisite">
 </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

So the Problem is:

As we can see in the second Xml-File (Xml after), changed the Prefix of `iconFile` from `asmv2:` to `p8`and in the same Node (`<description>`) it added a New Namespace called `p8` and this Namespce does not allow me to Update the Xmlfile (with Mage.exe)
So the solution would be : `<description iconFile="Icon.ico" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />`

or:`<description asmv2:iconFile="Icon.ico" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"  xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2"/>`

The Question is:

How can i enter into the `<description>` Node to delete/rename(if thats possible) the `p8` Namespace?

i tried it with:`doc.Root.Attribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "p8").Remove();` but it throws an exception called : System.NullReferenceException

Please help me out :)

As always you can correct me in anyway as long you're constructive :)

**Update/Answer:**

```
    var doc = XDocument.Load("Xmlfile");
    try
    {
        doc.Root.Attribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "asmv2").Remove();
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException) {}
    XNamespace ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2";
    doc.Descendants(ns + "dependentAssembly")
       .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("dependencyType") == "install")
       .Select(x => x.Parent)
       .Remove();
    doc.Descendants(ns + "file").Remove();
    doc.Save(filePath);
    foreach (var attr in doc.Descendants()
                            .SelectMany(d => d.Attributes())
                            .Where(a => a.Name.Namespace == ns))
     {
        attr.Parent.Add(new XAttribute(attr.Name.LocalName, attr.Value));
        attr.Remove();
     }
     doc.Save(filePath);
    }
```

Comment: Prefixes are not part of the name of the element. It's the element's Namespace written in a shorter way. {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-Instance}:Schema is the same as writing xsd:Schema (if the "xsd" prefix is linked to "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-Instance"). In this case you have 2 prefixes both pointing to the same namespace. Although not 'superclean' its completely legal. The "p8" is the generated prefix for a namespace. You cannot remove a namespace xmlns:p8="...." if the "p8" prefix is used anywhere by the elements in the XML. It would put the element in a 'unknown' namespace.

Comment: but if `iconFile` does not have any prefix (or asmv2 but i deleted it already) i have no problem to use tis file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your requirements correctly, you need something like:

```
foreach (var attr in doc.Descendants()
                        .SelectMany(d => d.Attributes())
                        .Where(a => a.Name.Namespace == ns))
{
   attr.Parent.Add(new XAttribute(attr.Name.LocalName, attr.Value));
   attr.Remove();
}
```